# Custom Shipping Method only for logged users

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, login, reward-points

Like in the title, i want to make **custom shipping method which will appears only for the logged users**.

I had reward points module, and i wanna make a "FreeShipping for Points" you can use the reward points only if you are logged in user so the shipping for points option have to be available only for logged users.

I already made custom shipping method based on http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747.

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Envato/Customshippingmethod/Model
class Envato_Customshippingmethod_Model_Demo
extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
  protected $_code = 'envato_customshippingmethod';

public function collectRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)) {
           return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

  public function getAllowedMethods()
  {
    return array(
      'envato_customshippingmethod' => $this->getConfigData('name'),
    );
  }

  protected function _isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        $regionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode();

        switch ($carrierCode) {
            case 'envato_customshippingmethod':
                if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


  protected function _getDefaultRate()
  {
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    $rate->setMethod($this->_code);
    $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    $rate->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
    $rate->setCost(0);

    return $rate;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite  the following class **`Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping`**

Step 1:Include following code in your config.xml

```
 <global> 
    <models>     
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping>Company_Module_Model_Shipping_Shipping</shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
    </models>
  </global>
```

Step 2 : your model class

```
class Company_Module_Model_Shipping_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)) {
           return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $carrierCode
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        $regionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode();

        switch ($carrierCode) {
            case 'flatrate':
                if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
            case 'freeshipping':
                if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see in above example, I have disables free shiping and fedex shipping method if user is not log-in.In the same way you customize you this code.

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe i made some mistakes, i edited my post and add my model class.

Comment: Create a new model app\code\local\Sipping\Disable\Model\Shipping\Shipping.php in this file use this code.

Comment: I don't understand why i need to create new model, i already have model for custom shipping, can i disable unlogged users from that model? Really i need to write another model?

Comment: As i can see your model class every things is ok make sure your shipping code is right,you can create new model for test or leave it